# background image size for all device in corona

Tags: graphics, coronasdk, screen-resolution

I am newbie in corona and want that back image should fit for all cross devices .
   please suggest me what should be size of my image and scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three versions of background images

- 320x480
- 720x1140
- 1440x2280

Then, use the below config.lua ( its ultimate config lua ) to support all possible devices

```
if string.sub(system.getInfo("model"),1,4) == "iPad" then
    application = 
    {
        content =
        {           
            fps = 60,
            width = 360,
            height = 480,
            scale = "letterBox",
            xAlign = "center",
            yAlign = "center",
            imageSuffix = 
            {
                ["@2x"] = 1.5,
                ["@4x"] = 3.0,
            },
        },
        notification = 
        {
            iphone = {
                types = {
                    "badge", "sound", "alert"
                }
            },
            google =
        {
                projectNumber = "xxxx",
         },
        }
    }

elseif string.sub(system.getInfo("model"),1,2) == "iP" and display.pixelHeight > 960 then
    application = 
    {
        content =
        {
            antialias = true,
            fps = 60,
            width = 320,
            height = 568,
            scale = "letterBox",
            xAlign = "center",
            yAlign = "center",
            imageSuffix = 
            {
                ["@2x"] = 1.5,
                ["@4x"] = 3.0
            },
        },
        notification = 
        {
            iphone = {
                types = {
                    "badge", "sound", "alert"
                }
            },
            google =
        {
                projectNumber = "xxxx",
         },
        }
    }

elseif string.sub(system.getInfo("model"),1,2) == "iP" then
    application = 
    {
        content =
        {
            antialias = true,
            fps = 60,
            width = 320,
            height = 480,
            scale = "letterBox",
            xAlign = "center",
            yAlign = "center",
            imageSuffix = 
            {
                ["@2x"] = 1.5,
                ["@4x"] = 3.0,
            },
        },
        notification = 
        {
            iphone = {
                types = {
                    "badge", "sound", "alert"
                }
            },
            google =
        {
                projectNumber = "xxxx",
         },
        }
    }
elseif display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth > 1.72 then
    application = 
    {
        content =
        {
            antialias = true,
            fps = 60,
            width = 320,
            height = 570,
            scale = "letterBox",
            xAlign = "center",
            yAlign = "center",
            imageSuffix = 
            {
                ["@2x"] = 1.5,
                ["@4x"] = 3.0,
            },
        },
    }
else
    application = 
    {
        content =
        {
            antialias = true,
            fps = 60,
            width = 320,
            height = 512,
            scale = "letterBox",
            xAlign = "center",
            yAlign = "center",
            imageSuffix = 
            {
                ["@2x"] = 1.5,
                ["@4x"] = 3.0,
            },
        },
        notification = 
        {
            iphone = {
                types = {
                    "badge", "sound", "alert"
                }
            },
            google =
        {
                projectNumber = "xxxx",
         },
        }
    }
end
```

Then read your background image in any of your lua file like below

```
local bgImage = display.newImageRect("textures/title/bg.png", 360, 570)
```

Comment: thnks @Arun but when i set width = 320,
            height = 480,
            scale = "zoomEven" then back image fits in all devices.

Comment: Thats okay. But that is not a recommended option. You must use scale = "letterBox" to avoid image pixcelation problem in higher resolution devices

Comment: thanks Arun three version of each image means same name with @2x or 4x at the end of image name ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Corona article on this subject, you'll want a different size than indicated by Arun's answer.

Here's a good [link to reference](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2010/11/20/content-scaling-made-easy/)

Basically, you'll want to use the "magic size" recomended on that link.

So that's 380 x 570. In Arun's answer (all respect, just trying to be clear) it was said to be 320 x 480.

In the recent trend of devices having retina and whatnot, we also need to strongly consider using the Corona "Ulimate Config" file, which is available here:
[Download for Corona Ultimate Config File](http://www.dropbox.com/s/yzs8bfc0drs4rwo/config.lua)

(For more details, you can read [this post that links to that file](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/).)

That will work for a lot of the diverse devices.

The takeaway, in  this modern era, is to create a file and two "larger" files with the suffix of "@2x" and "@4x"

- regular - 380 x 570 (width x height)
- @2x - 760 x 1140
- @4x - 1520 x 2280

then you can center it (code taken from third link) as such:

```
background = display.newImage( "background.png", true )
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

Comment: Thanks mike for your answer but is this code with assets suffix (@2x etc) applicable on android too or this just for apple devices ? thanks

Comment: Good question. I want to say just iOS. 
You may want to see what there is to glean [from this link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#launchimage)

This is for the Splash Screen, and may set you on the right track for determining proper background image sizes.